# CSS - Inline two divs and First Div should be at left and the second div should be at center position

Tags: jquery, html, css, styles, text-align

We need to provide two inline divs and first div should be at left and the second div should at center on a same line.

```
   <div style="margin-top:200px;">
        <div align="left" style="display:inline;">
            <label>Restrict to Primary Location:</label>
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                                                         .Name("ddl_restictToPrimaryLoc")
                                                         .DataTextField("Text")
                                                         .DataValueField("Value")
                                                         //.Events(e => e.Change("restictToPrimaryLocChange"))
                                                         .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
                  new SelectListItem() {
                      Text = "Yes",
                      Value = "1"
                  },
                  new SelectListItem() {
                      Text = "No",
                      Value = "0"
                  }})
                                .Value("1")
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 5%", @class = "form-control" }))
        </div>
        <div align="center" style="display:inline;">
            <button type="button" value="button" id="btn_AddSelection" class="jqButton  margin-bottom10">Add Selection</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

and it shows the UI in a state where both the divs on left align.

Please suggest.

Comment: is it necessary to use display:inline, because display:inline element will not take width so can not make center - An inline element will accept margin and padding, but the element still sits inline as you might expect. Margin and padding will only push other elements horizontally away, not vertically.

Answer (score 3):

You can use flexbox, but it would be hard to keep the second div centered considering not knowing which center you want(center of the entire line or center of the remaining empty space).

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}
.center-div{
  flex-grow:1;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:150px;" class="container">
        <div align="left" style="display:inline;" class="left-div">
            <label>Restrict to Primary Location:</label>      
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline;" class="center-div">
            <button type="button" value="button" id="btn_AddSelection" class="jqButton  margin-bottom10">Add Selection</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using a width specified for any screen on which your interface will be displayed. Having said that, with the full-screen width being considered as 100%, we can say that a `left div` will be approximately 33.33%, a `center div` will be another 33.33%, leaving a `right div` with the remaining 33.33%. Setting the division sizes as such, you can define the `left` and `center` divs that you create with these classes as shown below.

```css
#container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#left {
    float:left;
    width:33.33%;
    height: 20px;
}

#center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:33.33%;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="dropdown">Restrict to Primary Location:</label>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="btn_AddSelection"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <button id="btn_AddSelection" name="btn_AddSelection" class="btn btn-primary">Add Selection</button>
      </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```